# Basically, is “sexual intercourse“ (with wife) a positive or negative action? (Shia view)

Tags: hadith, shiism, sex

I know it is not Haram to have sexual intercourse with wife, but I wonder is it a positive act?

I mean:
 is it recommended(mustahab)? Or Makrooh (it means better not to do)?

*Any related hadith? (Shia view)*

Comment: It is considered a "sadqah", like every other good thing. It gives a way to fulfil one natural desires and stops one to seek illegal channels to fulfil this desire

Answer (score 8):

According to a hadith in Sahih Muslim, fullfilling sexual desires in lawful way is rewarded. See the following hadith (emphasize mine):

> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ أَسْمَاءَ الضُّبَعِيُّ،
>   حَدَّثَنَا مَهْدِيُّ بْنُ مَيْمُونٍ، حَدَّثَنَا وَاصِلٌ، مَوْلَى أَبِي
>   عُيَيْنَةَ عَنْ يَحْيَى بْنِ عُقَيْلٍ، عَنْ يَحْيَى بْنِ يَعْمَرَ،
>   عَنْ أَبِي الأَسْوَدِ الدِّيلِيِّ، عَنْ أَبِي، ذَرٍّ أَنَّ نَاسًا،
>   مِنْ أَصْحَابِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالُوا لِلنَّبِيِّ صلى
>   الله عليه وسلم يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ذَهَبَ أَهْلُ الدُّثُورِ
>   بِالأُجُورِ يُصَلُّونَ كَمَا نُصَلِّي وَيَصُومُونَ كَمَا نَصُومُ
>   وَيَتَصَدَّقُونَ بِفُضُولِ أَمْوَالِهِمْ ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ أَوَلَيْسَ قَدْ
>   جَعَلَ اللَّهُ لَكُمْ مَا تَصَّدَّقُونَ إِنَّ بِكُلِّ تَسْبِيحَةٍ
>   صَدَقَةً وَكُلِّ تَكْبِيرَةٍ صَدَقَةٌ وَكُلِّ تَحْمِيدَةٍ صَدَقَةٌ
>   وَكُلِّ تَهْلِيلَةٍ صَدَقَةٌ وَأَمْرٌ بِالْمَعْرُوفِ صَدَقَةٌ وَنَهْىٌ
>   عَنْ مُنْكَرٍ صَدَقَةٌ وَفِي بُضْعِ أَحَدِكُمْ صَدَقَةٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>   قَالُوا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ أَيَأْتِي أَحَدُنَا شَهْوَتَهُ وَيَكُونُ
>   لَهُ فِيهَا أَجْرٌ قَالَ ‏"‏ أَرَأَيْتُمْ لَوْ وَضَعَهَا فِي حَرَامٍ
>   أَكَانَ عَلَيْهِ فِيهَا وِزْرٌ فَكَذَلِكَ إِذَا وَضَعَهَا فِي
>   الْحَلاَلِ كَانَ لَهُ أَجْرٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> some of the people from among the Companions of the Messenger of Allah
>   (ﷺ) said to him: Messenger of Allah, the rich have taken away (all
>   the) reward. They observe prayer as we do; they keep the fasts as we
>   keep, and they give Sadaqa out of their surplus riches. Upon this he
>   (the Holy Prophet) said: Has Allah not prescribed for you (a course)
>   by following which you can (also) do sadaqa? In every declaration of
>   the glorification of Allah (i. e. saying Subhan Allah) there is a
>   Sadaqa, and every Takbir (i. e. saying Allah-O-Akbar) is a sadaqa, and
>   every praise of His (saying al-Hamdu Lillah) is a Sadaqa and every
>   declaration that He is One (La illha ill-Allah) is a sadaqa, and
>   enjoining of good is a sadaqa, and forbidding of that which is evil is
>   a Sadaqa, and in man's sexual Intercourse (with his wife, ) there is a
>   Sadaqa. **They (the Companions) said: Messenger of Allah, is there
>   reward for him who satisfies his sexual passion among us? He said:
>   Tell me, if he were to devote it to something forbidden, would it not
>   be a sin on his part? Similarly, if he were to devote it to something
>   lawful, he should have a reward.**
>
> ([Source](http://sunnah.com/muslim/12/66))

A [similiar hadith](http://sunnah.com/adab/11/7) exist in Al-Adab al-Mufrad, which is written by Al-Bukhari, and that hadith is graded hasan by [Albani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Nasiruddin_al-Albani). Therefore, **legal sexual intercourse is good thing**.

Answer (score 1):

Sex is a highly commercialized subject in today's society and a taboo sometimes in conservative societies unfortunately. In reality, it is an important need of any living being and it is natural to have desire for sexual intercourse for any person once he or she grows up.

God understands this and one of the reasons that God recommends getting married at the earliest is to allow the fulfillment of such desires besides having a companion with whom you can share and who can listen when you need someone besides you. In fact this physical relationship is an important ingredient in a successful marriage.